# external javascript libraries in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, samesite, calendly

I'm trying to implement various site plugins on my Angular app, and I'm having some issues.

Take for example Calendly. To implement the advice on their site is to add the following code snippet:

```
  <!-- Calendly link widget begin -->
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/mycalendar'});return false;">Schedule time with me</a>
<!-- Calendly link widget end -->
```

This obviously has some issues with regards to Angular - so I've hosted the https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js as file in the project and implemented it so it can be accessed from my component.

The issue presents itself, when the js tries to make a request to Calendly - I get this error:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://calendly.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

I hope there is a way around this short of writing my own implementation in something like a cloud function to avoid it?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Angular has a Security Sanitizer to use with external scripts and links, maybe can help you:
https://angular.io/guide/security#xss

Comment: The error say that your local env is not allowed to consume those files from the server, try to download and serve by an assets